# pandas create feature where id value occurs in previous month

Tags: pandas

I have data in a pandas dataframe like this:

```
id | month | count
-------------------
01 | 1 | 517
02 | 1 | 283
01 | 2 | 123
02 | 2 | 321
03 | 2 | 332
```

So the same id can appear against different months, but sometimes this is not the case. (e.g. in example above, id 03 doesn't appear in month 1.

What I'm trying to do is create a new column `previous_month_count` which looks back to see if the id appears in the previous month, and returns the count or if there is no previous month count, returns null or 0.

```
dup = df
dup = dup.rename(columns={"month": "previous_month"}, inplace=True)
df['previous_month'] = df['month'] -1
df.merge(dup[['count']], on=['id','previous_month'])
```

This generates

> KeyError: 'month'

But the desired effect is to merge the previous month's count with the current month's count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using your own code

```
dup = df.copy()
dup.rename(columns={"month": "previous_month"}, inplace=True)
df['previous_month'] = df['month'] -1
df.merge(dup, on=['id','previous_month'],how='left')



Out[358]: 
   id  month  count_x  previous_month  count_y
0   1      1      517               0      NaN
1   2      1      283               0      NaN
2   1      2      123               1    517.0
3   2      2      321               1    283.0
4   3      2      332               1      NaN
```

Comment: @joshi123 yes : -)